# Streamlit Session being shared with multiple users

Tags: python, caching, session-state, streamlit

So I am making a Stream lit web application with python. Here is the link to the app: https://jensen-holm-mlb-simapp-app-kclnz9.streamlitapp.com/

I have already deployed the app but have come across a strange problem. When I booted the app it worked great, running simulations for the two teams that I put into it. But after I do this first run, I put two other teams into it. But the simulation yields the same results from the first two teams. I know this because if i try the download play by polay button, it is always the same players from the first simulation. Very weird problem I did not forsee. Even when run on another persons computer, it still yields the same results as it did for that first test I ran on my computer.

I would really like it to re run everything when you enter two different teams and hit go again. Which I thought happens by default.

Any help is greatly appriciated, below is the main app.py file that I am running in the cloud. Here is a link to the github repo: https://github.com/Jensen-holm/MLB-Simapp

```
import sqlite3
import streamlit as st
from objects import Team
import game_functions
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_df(df):
    return df.to_csv().encode("utf-8")

# title and stuff
st.set_page_config(page_title = 'Ball.Sim (Beta)', page_icon = '⚾️')
st.title('Ball.Sim (Beta)')
st.write('\nCreated by Jensen Holm')
st.write('Data Source: [Sports-Reference](https://sports-reference.com)')
st.write('\n[Donate](https://www.paypal.com/donate/?business=HPLUVQJA6GFMN&no_recurring=0&currency_code=USD)')

# get rid of streamlit option menu stuff
# hide_streamlit_style = """
#             <style>
#             #MainMenu {visibility: hidden;}
#             footer {visibility: hidden;}
#             </style>
#             """

# st.markdown(hide_streamlit_style, unsafe_allow_html=True) 

# import the player data dict dictionaries for the keys so we can have options in the select box
sim_data_db = sqlite3.connect("Sim_Data.db")

# get list of all table names with the cursor to put into the st.select_box
all_teams_array = np.array(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", sim_data_db))

# the all teams array is nested so lets unnest it
all_teams_with_year = []
for sublist in all_teams_array:
    for thing in sublist:
        all_teams_with_year.append(thing)

all_teams = [team[len('Year '):] for team in all_teams_with_year]
all_teams.sort()
all_teams.insert(0, "Start typing and select team")

# user unput buttons and sliders

team1 = st.selectbox(label = "Team 1", options = all_teams)
team2 = st.selectbox(label = "Team 2", options = all_teams)

number_of_simulations = st.slider("Number of Simulations", min_value = 162, max_value = 16200, step = 162)

# initialize simulation button
init_button = st.button("Go")
if init_button:

    if team1 == "Start typing and select team" or team2 == "Start typing and select team":
        st.error("Must select team from select boxes.")
        st.stop()

    # select databse tables based on user input
    team1_data = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM 'Year {team1}'", con = sim_data_db)
    team2_data = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM 'Year {team2}'", con = sim_data_db)

    team1_year = team1[:5]
    team2_year = team1[:5]
    team1_name = team1[5:]
    team2_name = team2[5:]

    # generate teams with the data queried above
    Team1 = Team(team1_name, team1_year, team1_data, lineup_settings = 'auto')
    Team2 = Team(team2_name, team2_year, team2_data, lineup_settings = 'auto')

    # begin simulation
    pbp_df = game_functions.simulation(number_of_simulations, Team1, Team2, 0)

    # make it a csv and use st.download_button()
    pbp_csv = convert_df(pbp_df)
    st.download_button("Download Play By Play Data", pbp_csv, file_name = "BallSimPBP.csv")


    # use st.tabs to filter what to see, like a chart tab for the graph, a place where they can view stats per 162 for each player
    # and download data and stuff on another one (may need to figure out the st.session state thing tho)


# footer type stuff, plugging myself.
st.write(f'\n\nFeedback and report bugs: holmj@mail.gvsu.edu')
st.write('\nSocials: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JensenH_) [GitHub](https://github.com/Jensen-holm) [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jensen-holm-3584981bb/)')
st.write('[Documentation / Code](https://github.com/Jensen-holm/MLB-Simapp)')
```